# Script to know the page load time

Tags: android, python, browser, html

I am trying to know the page load time of a webpage on Android smartphone. I don't want the network delay, so I am using the pages already stored on my smartphone (Android device).

I know that following 2 parts would work:

```
<head> ***Time printing code 1***

<body ***Time printing code 2***
```

On subtraction of those 2 timing should give me page load time.

I am able to get those in form of pop up i.e. when page loads, it pops the load time (by subtracting those 2 times). I am looking a way to automate it as in it should print this or write it in a text file and I can read directly from there.